# c++ objects of same class with different initial condition after constructed

Tags: c++, class, constructor, codeblocks

I create a class with name well, and it has a function to print its state; after I construct them writing as "well w1, w2, w3 ....., w10;" 8 or 9 of them prints same state but 1 or 2 of them prints another state (there are total 4 states I defined and initially it has a default state which 8-9 of the objects prints correctly).

I use CodeBlocks and I added the well class by " #include "well.h" " .
So in short; i define a class and create objects by just writing their name and some of them behave different than others.

```
enter code here




#include <iostream>
#include "myQueue.h"
#include "well.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main(){


Well w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6,w7,w8,w9,w10;
w1.checkState(); 
w1.printState();
w2.checkState(); 
w2.printState();
w3.checkState(); 
w3.printState();
w4.checkState(); 
w4.printState();
w5.checkState(); 
w5.printState();
w6.checkState(); 
w6.printState();
w7.checkState(); 
w7.printState();
w8.checkState(); 
w8.printState();
w9.checkState(); 
w9.printState();
w10.checkState();
w10.printState();

return 0;
}

    class implementation




include "well.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

Well::Well()
{
    int state = 4;
    int day = 1;
    float storage = 2.0;
    int offday = 0;
    int useCount = 0;
}

int Well::checkState()
{
    if (storage==0)
        {if (useCount==2) state = 3; // dry and broken
         else state = 1;}    //dry
    else if (useCount==2) state = 2;   //broken
    else state = 4;         // available
}

void Well::printState()
{
    if (state==1) cout << "d" << endl;
    else if (state==2) cout << "b" << endl;
    else if (state==3) cout << "db" << endl;
    else if(state==4) cout << "avai"<< endl;
}

void Well::GFG()

{
    checkState();
    if (state !=2 ) {storage= min(5.0,storage + 0.5 );
        checkState(); };
}

void Well::SP()
{
    if (state == 4 )
    {
        storage = max(0.0, storage-1.0);
        useCount++;
        checkState();
    }
}

float Well::getStorage() const
{
    return storage;
}
void Well::newDay()
{
    ++day;
    GFG();
    --offday;
    useCount=0;
    checkState();
}




     on screen




avai
avai
d
avai 
avai
avai
avai
d
avai
avai
```

Comment: Rather than have us guess, could you please post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Well, you likely have some uninitialized state, but its really hard to guess what you are doing wrong with more info.

Comment: There's no need to vote to close when, as here, the mistake is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
Well::Well()
{
    int state = 4;
    int day = 1;
    float storage = 2.0;
    int offday = 0;
    int useCount = 0;
}
```

doesn't initialize member of the class. It initializes local variables in the constructor. Up your compiler's warning level to get warnings about such unused variables.

Here's a variant that initializes the members:

```
Well::Well()
    : state( 4 )
    , day( 1 )
    , storage( 2.0 )
    , offday( 0 )
    , useCount( 0 )
{}
```

Check your favorite C++ textbook for the initialization syntax.